# Explode R dataframe

Tags: r, pandas

I'm trying to reproduce the pandas (Python) explode method using R.

This is the data I have:

```
d = {"SN":[1,2],"Age":[21,15],"Name":["John;Luis","Dora"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df
```

From there I use split the names separated by ";" and use the explode method

```
df["Name"] = df["Name"].apply(lambda x: x.split(";"))
df.explode("Name")
```

The result I get is:

[image]

Now I'm trying to do the same using R.
I have this part of the code, that accounts for the first step

```
df <- data.frame("SN" = 1:2, "Age" = c(21,15), "Name" = c("John;Luis","Dora"))
df$Name <- as.character(df$Name)
df = df %>% 
    mutate(Name =  strsplit(Name,split=';', fixed=TRUE) )
```

But I'm not finding the equivalent to `.explode()`

Comment: fyi, `df['Name'].str.split(';')` is a shorthand for `.apply(...)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `separate_rows` in `R` instead of `strsplit` and then expand the rows

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)   
df %>%
     separate_rows(Name)
#  SN Age Name
#1  1  21 John
#2  1  21 Luis
#3  2  15 Dora
```

---

With the OP method, the `strsplit` returns a `list` of `vector`, which can be `unnest`ed

```
df %>% 
   mutate(Name =  strsplit(Name,split=';', fixed=TRUE) ) %>%
   unnest(c(Name))
```